# What is the use of GPIO Locking mechanism?

Tags: microcontroller

[image]

I came across this on one of the STM32 uC's reference manual and I really have no idea about the use case of this feature. I might be having a very narrow approach because I feel that it doesn't have any use case because the person who is coding for it will be taking care that he/she doesn't change the GPIO configuration at any random point of time.

That is what I feel and I don't see any practical use case of this particular feature but I really doubt because people at STM wouldn't have put something without any thought process. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I could think about the case of a bootloader, which might want to reserve some GPIOs and not let the "user" program mess with them.

Comment: Also a little google search is revealing a simple answer on a forum: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/purpose-of-locking-gpio-on-stm32f4s/

Comment: @EugeneSh. Did google search. Look's more like location thing because I didn't see any fruitful result in first few pages. If it is only there so that the person who is coding doesn't change the gpio configuration in middle, I am quite disappionted.

Comment: Why are you disappointed? Again, think of a bootloader case. Consider a platform, such as... say Arduino, which is not the MCU only but a full board, where some GPIOs are connected to some sensitive stuff and will burn something if sourcing current, but only after some boot sequence. Then the chip has a bootloader that is provided by the vendor, who knows how to properly perform this sequence. But this bootloader will allow the end-user (a hobbyist or whosoever) to load and run their own programs. You don't want let them burn the board that easily.

Comment: *"... THE person who is coding ..."* Have you never worked on multi-person projects?

Comment: I would find this usefull in a critical I/O setup where I would not want any potential bugs or security issue mess up the specific state of GPIOs.  The state of the GPIOs could be life critical or security critical - whatever.  Sure, if they should not change, the program will not be coded to change them.  But if they are critical, it is better risk management to have them locked once they are set.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have worked, but the idea basically is GPIO is one to one with external pheripheral so you set config right at the starting and not modify it anywhere. If somebody does change your gpio configuration , he/she isn't actually reading documents properly and would not get their thing running. so pretty can be solved right in the testing by the developer itself? Are there any other approach ?

Comment: Right after making the previous comment , It did struck to me that changing the gpio config may burn the gpio pin.